# Webscraping : How to match a string with Instr function

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

i'm performing a web-scraping on the ecb's website for annual report in order to practice more. After i find all pdf's href of the page, i get loads of string like this:

```
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/annrep/ar2016en.pdf?cb49eb74de9ddf1f55ebe03fb610d05b
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/annrep/ar2015en.pdf?2e7998c5daf6a2a7e4bfccb41e81b504
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/annrep/ar2014en.pdf?20def41d1b09b84d5889c707f92c9e4a
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/annrep/ar2013en.pdf?fad3a17bf210c3c411c6e3c3121eb8a1
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/annrep/ar2012en.pdf?40f7b4588f9adb8cf61ce44014c1b088
```

And so on.

Now i would like to perform an action that if the string that the user submit is CONTAINED in one of those href, it clicks on the href. (for example i insert 2015 and it clicks on the second href)

I tried with Instr but it works only if i insert the full href.

My code is this:

```
Sub prova()

Dim Ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim Iedoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim element As Object
Dim elements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim parameter As String

parameter = "2015" 'i will insert application.inputbox


With Ie:
    .navigate "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/annual/html/index.en.html"
    .Visible = True
End With

While Ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or Ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

Set Iedoc = Ie.document

Set elements = Iedoc.getElementsByClassName("pdf")

For Each element In elements:
    If InStr(1, parameter, element) Then
    element.Click
    End If
    Debug.Print element
    Next element
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Instr` expects a string, not an object, as the param to search in.

[Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

> InStr([ start ], string1, string2, [ compare ])

The ordering is also:

> string1   Required. String expression being searched.
>
> string2   Required. String expression sought

Dependant on which string you are searching for, and its location, you might choose [InStrRev](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function) to search from the end of the source string for a faster match. Note the arguments are then:

> InstrRev(stringcheck, stringmatch, [ start, [ compare ]])

Technically, I think it is a param in the signature but an argument when value passed. Though someone can correct me if wrong.

You should use the `href`

```
InStr(1, href, param) >0
```

at a push you could use the `outerHTML` but you have a larger search space so less efficient.

It is yet more efficient to simply use the DOM parser to filter the results using a css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector with contains * , starts with ^,  or ends with $ operator:

`contains` operator:

```
Iedoc.querySelector("[href*='" &  parameter & "'").click
```

It would be safer to test for a longer substring in the `href` attribute so something like:

```
param = 2015 
Iedoc.querySelector(".doc-title [href*='/pub/annual/html/ar" & param & "']").click
```

then you get rid of entire loop.

---

**Side-notes:**

In your current loop you would also likely want an `Exit For` after match found.

`Debug.Print element` will, if match found, simply print `[Object]`.

You would want to access a property of the element itself e.g. `.innerText`. However, given you just clicked on it, you risk a stale element exception bubbling up (or some other error) if element is now no longer attached to the DOM.

Comment: This is really useful, i should read more about .queryselector. Do you know where i can find some material to learn it? Furthermore, with the string "Iedoc.querySelector("[href*='https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/annrep/ar" & param & "']").click" how you manage to ignore everything that comes after "param" ?

Comment: Because the * is a contains operator which basically says whatever the actual string is it only needs to contain the string after the =

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector  In VBA it is usually applied as a method of HTMLDocument e.g. ie.document.querySelector

Comment: I'm trying with .queryselector but it doesn't seems working.  It says "Object variable or With variable not set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198442/discussion-between-zakiirim-and-qharr).

Comment: Iedoc.querySelector(".doc-title [href*='/pub/annual/html/ar" & param & "']").click